# UserManager.FindByNameAsync() doesn't return anything at all

Tags: asp.net, angular, asynchronous, controller, backend

I need to get the user with some username but the function call seemingly does nothing. I'm using the exact same call in a different controller and it's working just fine.
This is the line:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
```

When I put a break point on this line and the line below it, the debugger stops on this line, and when I try to go to the next line it just pauses for a bit and skips the rest of the function. As a result the controller function also doesn't return anything. Both controllers where I use call this function have the exact same declarations for _userManager and use it in the same way. Only difference is that the one that works gets its parameter from a passed objects property, whereas the other one just uses a string.

Please help I'm starting to lose my hair.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you initially create the user using the `CreateAsync` method of a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager instance. If you create the user by adding it directly using Entity Framework, you won't be able to find it using `FindByNameAsync`.

Comment: Why is this so ?

Comment: How do I fix this if it is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Anybody facing this issue because they couldn't create users using "CreateAsync" or they have an already existing set of users, apply this solution.

Make sure the users in your database who where not created using the "CreateAsync" method of the user manager pass through the following.

```
    //Get the corresponding user by id
    var usr2 = _userManager.FindByIdAsync("youruserid").Result;

    //Apply the following updates to the user model in the database
    var res = await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(usr2);
    await _userManager.UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(usr2);
    await _userManager.UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(usr2);
    await _userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(usr2, true);
```

Apply the above code to every user in your database that was not created using "CreateAsync".
After these steps, you'll now be able to Find your user by username and email.
Note: If your users weren't assigned claims, don't forget to assign claims in the Database.

Comment: FindByIdAsync also returns null for my user, I did verify it's in the database